# Filter pandas Dataframe based on max values in a column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame with repeating values in the index. I would like to filter this dataset down to only show me one instance of each index by selecting the row within the index with the greatest value in a different column. For example, my DataFrame looks like this:

df:

```
Product ID     Store     Sales
    1            A         50
    1            B        200
    1            C         20
    2            A        400
    2            B         10
    3            A        200
    4            A         50
    4            B        100
    4            C        500
```

I would like to filter this data down to this:

df2:

```
Product ID     Store     Sales
    1            B        200
    2            A        400
    3            A        200
    4            C        500
```

Any thoughts on how best to approach this issue in pandas?

Thanks very much for your time -

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can perform a `groupby` on 'Product ID', then apply `idxmax` on 'Sales' column.
This will create a series with the index of the highest values.
We can then use the index values to index into the original dataframe using `iloc`

```
In [201]:

df.iloc[df.groupby('Product ID')['Sales'].agg(pd.Series.idxmax)]
Out[201]:
   Product_ID Store  Sales
1           1     B    200
3           2     A    400
5           3     A    200
8           4     C    500
```

Comment: Similar solution w/o the duplicates: `df.iloc[df.groupby('Product ID')['Sales'].idxmax().values.ravel()]`

Comment: @TomAugspurger actually it works without `drop_duplicates`, I originally was using `transform` but using `agg` also works and doesn't require dropping duplicates. I will update my answer

Comment: @TomAugspurger when I was using `transform` it was trying to align the results to the original df and so repeated the index values as we had multiple 'Store' rows for each 'Product ID' this was why I had `drop_duplicates` but I realised this was unnecessary as an aggregate function with `idxmax` would work fine