# Fillter the largest n values of a column using another column as index in Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, max

I have a dataframe with 4 columns. I would like to get the largest 40 values of one column (column ey) for each data input in column N, while keeping the data of the other 2 columns (ie: I wouldnt like to delete or lose the data of the other two columns).

The question is very similar to this post: [Filter pandas Dataframe based on max values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071937/filter-pandas-dataframe-based-on-max-values-in-a-column). The difference is that I am looking for the 40 largest values, and not the largest value, and also that my dataframe has more columns.

The table below is an example of the table I have, while it only has 4 rows in each column N dataset (actual dataframe has many more rows for each N).

```
N   Ret upside_tri  ey
1   -0.1478 -14.4097 -0.3702
1   0.7571  -9.4190 -0.4609
1   -0.0045 -1.0086 0.0272
1   0.3458  -7.1714 0.0000
2   -0.1218 -9.7807 -1.5318
2   0.2283  14.7490 -0.2328
2   0.2798  -0.4965 0.1343
2   0.2273  0.0770  0.0368
3   0.0904  0.1881  -0.2433
3   -0.0526 1.8242  0.2686
3   0.0822  4.9049  -0.0416
3   0.2182  -1.0752 -0.0331
4   0.0201  4.6152  0.2242
4   0.0527  -0.3465 0.1953
4   0.1169  -1.2500 -0.0266
4   -0.1854 2.7845  0.0947
5   0.0192  -0.4258 0.1783
5   -0.0319 0.9984  0.2314
5   0.0800  1.9057  0.2101
5   -0.0447 -0.5313 0.0865
```

Assuming I would like the 2 largest values of ey for each N (my actual wish is to have the 40 largest values), the desired outcome would become something like this:

```
N   Return  upside  ey
1   -0.0045 -1.0086 0.0272
1   0.3458  -7.1714 0.0000
2   0.2798  -0.4965 0.1343
2   0.2273  0.0770  0.0368
3   -0.0526 1.8242  0.2686
3   0.2182  -1.0752 -0.0331
4   0.0201  4.6152  0.2242
4   0.0527  -0.3465 0.1953
5   -0.0319 0.9984  0.2314
5   0.0800  1.9057  0.2101
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option without using `.apply()` and lambda function.

#### Use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.nlargest()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

(with all vectorized operations for faster execution):

```
df.loc[df.groupby('N')['ey'].nlargest(2).reset_index(0).index]
```

**Result:**

```
    N     Ret  upside_tri      ey
2   1 -0.0045     -1.0086  0.0272
3   1  0.3458     -7.1714  0.0000
6   2  0.2798     -0.4965  0.1343
7   2  0.2273      0.0770  0.0368
9   3 -0.0526      1.8242  0.2686
11  3  0.2182     -1.0752 -0.0331
12  4  0.0201      4.6152  0.2242
13  4  0.0527     -0.3465  0.1953
17  5 -0.0319      0.9984  0.2314
18  5  0.0800      1.9057  0.2101
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm! How do you paste the tables formatted so nicely here in Stackoverflow? Everytime I have to paste a dataframe here the format looks bad.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df1 = df.groupby('N').apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(n = 2, columns= ['ey'])).reset_index(drop=True)
```